# Find the number of digit(s) of the factorial of an integer in a certain base

Tags: c, radix, factorial

My solution was pretty fast but not enough. I need more faster. How can I reduce my time?
Input Number:  n (0 ≤ n ≤ 1000000)
Base should be: base (2 ≤ base ≤ 1000)

1. Input 5! in 10 base. Output is: 3
2. Input 22! in 3 base. Output is: 45

Time Limit: 2 second(s), and Memory Limit: 32 MB

Here is my code in c language:

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int factorialDigitExtended ( int n, int base ) {
    double x = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
        x += log10 ( i ) / log10(base);
    }
    int res = ( (int) x ) + 1;
    return res;
}

int main(){
    int i, t, n, b;
    for(i=1; i<= t; i++){
        scanf("%d %d", &n, &b);
        printf("Case %d: %d\n", i, factorialDigitExtended(n, b));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring execution time? Execution time depends a lot on the machine you're using, is there a specific setup you have in mind?

Comment: Please define "faster"

Comment: There's 'closed form' formula approximating factorial, should be win for ya: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: This is a a code review question, you must ask it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Time Limit: 2 second(s), and Memory Limit: 32 MB

Comment: Time limit for which n?

Comment: `log()` / `log10()` not needed to solve this task.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in the comment above this might be target specific behavior. A few things I would look at:

Only calculate constant values once:

```
int factorialDigitExtended ( int n, int base ) {
    double x = 0;
    double lbase = log10(base);
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
        x += log10 ( i ) / lbase;
    }
    int res = ( (int) x ) + 1;
    return res;
}
```

Division may be expensive:

```
int factorialDigitExtended ( int n, int base ) {
    double x = 0;
    double lbase = 1 / log10(base);
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
        x += log10 ( i ) * lbase;
    }
    int res = ( (int) x ) + 1;
    return res;
}
```

Don't repeat the same multiplication n times:

```
int factorialDigitExtended ( int n, int base ) {
    double x = 0;
    double lbase = 1 / log10(base);
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
        x += log10 ( i );
    }
    x *= lbase;
    int res = ( (int) x ) + 1;
    return res;
}
```

0 compare might be cheaper:

```
int factorialDigitExtended ( int n, int base ) {
    double x = 0;
    double lbase = 1 / log10(base);
    for ( int i = n; i > 0; --i ) {
        x += log10 ( i );
    }
    x *= lbase;
    int res = ( (int) x ) + 1;
    return res;
}
```

Btw (int) x might fail at some points due to precision problems.

There might also be processor specific logarithm instructions.

Comment: `log` may be slightly faster than `log10`.